# adding wait for a loop in javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

I wanna run a loop in javaScript like this

for (conditions) {
    do something;
    **wait for a second** 
}

How to make the portion of the condition typed in bold (delaying the condition for a second) ?

Comment: `window.setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout - but you'll have to restructure your looping

Answer (score 2):

```
timeTillWarning = 10;

setTimeout(looping, 1000);

function looping() {
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
    setTimeout(looping, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just want to add that this works great but KEEP IN MIND that any time in your logic code is added on top of the waiting time.  I've run into issues where at the end my timer was off by a second or two because of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 100;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  // do something
  i--;
  if (i == 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```